# Firebase Storage Custom metadata security rule for list of uids

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I'm developing a messaging iOS app, where a user can send the same message to multiple people. The message is saved in firebase storage. I want to only enable the users who have been sent the message to be able to read it from storage. I am already implementing this rule structure in my firebase database.

In order to implement this for storage I add a list of uids to the message file customMetadata, including a fromUid key for the person who composed the message. I do the following in my iOS app:

```
    var metadataValues = [String:String]()

    for friendUid in friendsSelected.keys {
        metadataValues.updateValue(friendUid, forKey: friendUid) // how do I access these values in my security rules
    }
    metadataValues.updateValue(senderUid, forKey: "fromUid") // how do I access this in security rules 
    let messageMetadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
    messageMetadata.customMetadata = metadataValues
```

This was my attempt for my read and write security rules for the messages node in Firebase Storage but it doesn't work and the documentation is of no help.

```
    match /messages/{messageId} {

        allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.metadata.request.auth.uid; // I want all friend uids to be able to read file
        allow write: if request.auth.uid == resource.metadata.fromUid; // only the person who create the message can access it

}
```

My attempt doesn't work. How do I access the customMetadata variable with the keys 'fromUid' and the friends uids 'request.auth.uid' in my security rules??

As a sidenote, I assume there is no limit on how many keys I add to customMetadata?

Comment: would really appreciate help on this. For some reason everything I have tried hasn't worked.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So I have managed to solve it. The problem I had was that I wasn't familiar with Javascript and so I was getting the syntax wrong. After looking into Javascript I was soon able to work it out.

Hope my answer helps anyone else but would recommend learning the basics of Javascript if you are in a similar position to me.

It's also worth noting that to access the file metadata you use `request.resource.metadata` before the write is executed and `resource.metadata` to access once uploaded.

```
    match /messages/{messageId} {
    
        allow write: if request.resource.metadata['fromUid'] == request.auth.uid; 
        allow read: if resource.metadata[request.auth.uid] == request.auth.uid; 
    }
```

Comment: Have you figured out if the metadata has a limit for the number of friends?.

Comment: A little late but i stumbled across this: "There is a maximum combined size limit for all custom metadata keys and values of 8 KiB per object."
https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#objects
So the limit is somewhere around 250 friends with standard uids.